# Angularjs:-month calendar to week calendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar

I am a newbie and was building a calendar in angularjs.So far I have been successful and have made a calendar based on monthly basis.

The following is code I have implemented.

```
  var calendarFactory = function(calMonth){
                var calendar = [],
                    monthMoment = moment().month(calMonth).startOf('month');
                _.each(_.range(moment().month(calMonth).startOf('month').day()),function(item){
                    calendar.push("");
                });

                _.each(_.range(1,moment().month(calMonth).startOf('month').daysInMonth() + 1), function(item){
                    var day = {
                        day_value:item,
                        day_name: moment().month(calMonth).startOf('month').add('days',(item - 1)).format("ddd").toUpperCase(),
                        api_date: moment().month(calMonth).startOf('month').add('days',(item - 1)).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                        clickable: ( calMonth > moment().month() ? true : item >= moment().format('D'))
                    };
                    calendar.push(day);
                });

                _.each(_.range(7 - (moment().month(calMonth).startOf('month').endOf('month').day() + 1)),function(item){
                    calendar.push("");
                });

                return calendar;
            };
```

But now I want to implement the same code on a weekly basis.I am a bit stuck up at how to do it so far.I am not sure as to how to convert the code for calendar on weekly basis.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: once i implemented this using javaScript..

Comment: @Ved..Can You help me with this..Am a bit confused.

Comment: ok.. I am posting my code..

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/u93g87qc/2/

```
function GetDates(startDate, daysToAdd) {
  var aryDates = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <= daysToAdd; i++) {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
   aryDates.push(DayAsString(currentDate.getDay()) + ", " + currentDate.getDate() + " " + MonthAsString(currentDate.getMonth()) + " " + currentDate.getFullYear());
  }

  return aryDates;
 }

 function MonthAsString(monthIndex) {
  var d=new Date();
  var month=new Array();
  month[0]="Jan";
  month[1]="Feb";
  month[2]="March";
  month[3]="April";
  month[4]="May";
  month[5]="June";
  month[6]="July";
  month[7]="Aug";
  month[8]="Sep";
  month[9]="Oct";
  month[10]="Nov";
  month[11]="Dec";

  return month[monthIndex];
 }

 function DayAsString(dayIndex) {
  var weekdays = new Array(7);
  weekdays[0] = "Sun";
  weekdays[1] = "Mon";
  weekdays[2] = "Tue";
  weekdays[3] = "Wed";
  weekdays[4] = "Thu";
  weekdays[5] = "Fri";
  weekdays[6] = "Sat";

  return weekdays[dayIndex];
 }

 var startDate = new Date();
 var aryDates = GetDates(startDate, 7);
 console.log(aryDates);
```